# Can't get out of if statement which is in TSQL : trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

This is my trigger which is supposed to prevent the user to inter "@" , "$" or "_"  in City . If has two condition and it works perfectly

```
ALTER TRIGGER i_validation
ON dbo.Customer
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @i_not NVARCHAR(200)
begin
    SELECT @i_not = dbo.Customer.City 
    FROM dbo.Customer 
    JOIN inserted ON dbo.Customer.CustomerID = inserted.CustomerID

    IF((@i_not LIKE '%@%') OR (@i_not LIKE '%$%'))
    BEGIN
        THROW 50000, 'First name cannot contain: "@" ,"$" ,or "_"', 1;
    END;
END
```

But when I add the third condition :

```
1Version.IF(( @i_not LIKE '%@%') OR ( @i_not LIKE '%$%') or @i_not LIKE '%_%' ) 
2Version. IF((( @i_not LIKE '%@%') OR ( @i_not LIKE '%$%')) OR @i_not LIKE '%_%' )
```

I also tried second if additional else if

```
ALTER TRIGGER i_validation
ON dbo.Customer
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @i_not NVARCHAR(200)
BEGIN
    SELECT @i_not = dbo.Customer.City 
    FROM dbo.Customer 
    JOIN inserted ON dbo.Customer.CustomerID = inserted.CustomerID

    IF ((@i_not LIKE '%@%') OR (@i_not LIKE '%$%'))
    BEGIN
        THROW 50000, 'First name cannot contain: "@" ,"$" ,or "_"', 1;
    END;
    ELSE IF (@i_not LIKE '%_%')
    BEGIN
        THROW 50000, 'First name cannot contain: "@" ,"$" ,or "_"', 1;
    END
END
```

But result, it whether ignores or works every time even though city does not contain @ , $, _ .

Are there any other ways to use if with 3 conditions?

Comment: Another thought - why does this matter? Why bother? There are many other characters that likely shouldn't be allowed - yet you don't check for those. In addition, your error message is completely misleading - you check the associated city, not the first name.

Comment: I did the same for Firstname input also, I just copy-pasted and forgot to change. I wanted to know how I can use if with 3 conditions

Answer (score 6):

The reason your checks fail is that [underscore is a special character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) when you use it with `LIKE`.  It matches any single character, just like `%` matches any text.

But why not use a check constraint?

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD CONSTRAINT check1 CHECK (City not like '%[@$_]%');
```

Here `[@$_]` is a character range matching either `@`, `$` or `_`. An underscore has no special meaning in a character range.